# How to partially bold a Paragraph in Apache POI? (Word Documents)

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I been working with Apache POI recently and i can't figure out how to set a string like this: "Hello **World**". This is what i been trying

```
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    String path = System.getProperty("user.home")+ "/Desktop/"+ array.get(0); //"array" is an ArrayList<String>
    path = path.replace("\\","/");
            
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
    String str1 = "Price: ";
    String str2 = array.get(1); // This needs to be Bold
    run.setFontSize(9);
    run.setFontFamily("Arial");
    run.setText(str1);
    run.setBold(true);
    run.setText(str2);
    paragraph.setSpacingBetween(1);
    paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
    try {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(ruta);
        document.write(output);
        output.close();
        document.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I know that "run.setBold(true)" its supposed to apply it to the whole parapraph but its the only thing i found for word documents so i need some help to fix this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want to a) Create a run, b) Apply "bold" to the run, and c) Add your text to the run.  A  "run" is *NOT* a "paragraph" - the two are completely different!

Comment: @paulsm4 But with the run you can modify the parapraph, right? Sorry if i'm wrong:(

Comment: @paulsm4 Yeah, but I dont want the full parapraph to be bold, just the str2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,  a run is a run, and a paragraph is a paragraph; they are different things. You can make the run a single word, adjacent words or an entire paragraph. The only thing that matters is a) if you want to "bold" something, then b) you need to "bold" the corresponding run.

Confusing things, in POI you create a "run" in terms of a "paragraph" :(

... BUT ...

You can have multiple runs - with different attributes - in the *SAME* paragraph.

For example:

```
  XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun r1 = p.createRun();
  r1.setText("Some Text");
  r1.setBold(true);
  r2 = p.createRun();
  r2.setText("Goodbye");
```

I haven't tried this code, but I believe "Some Text" will be bold, and "Goodbye" won't.  You can also experiment with different syntax, to see what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it really helped me to understood the difference between run and paragraph:)
I wasnt aware that you could have more than one run for each paragraph

Comment: In Microsoft Word, a paragraph is made up of one or more runs. Everything in a run has the same style. That's just how Word "works", and that's what Apache POI implements!